# How do I stop other domains from pointing to my domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dns

I recently found out that there are other domain names pointing to my website (that don't belong to me) and I was wondering how people can stop/prevent this from happening. I'm hosting this on peer1 using IIS and I'm using ASP.NET C#.

Can I use an HttpModule or some other code to reject domain names that aren't mine?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Your site doesn't control what DNS records point to the IP address of your server.

Comment: But can't you find out the domain name of where the request came from?  If you could find out, you could then redirect to another page.  Don't some sites do this to prevent hot linking?

Comment: Could you update the question with details about your hosting environment.  Are you hosting this site yourself or is it with a hosting company.  What is the web server (guessing IIS) and do you have administrative access to it.

Comment: Is your problem that they are including your site in a frame?

Comment: Can you answer Bob's question - are they including the site in a frame, or are you having problems with them hotlinking content as bemused has suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should activate name-based virtual hosting and only show your real website for the desired domain names. For all other names, you can display a suitable error message.

**Details:** Your webserver is contacted by its IP address. There is nothing you can do to stop that. Anyone can say, "connect to that IP address". For instance, anyone can register new domain names to point to your server's IP address. However, inside the request, there is a field `Host` with a name like `www.example.com`.

Upon receiving the request, your server may choose to inspect the `Host` field and deliver different content depending on that value. In the simplest case, the server ignores the field entirely and always prints out the same content. But in a more sophisticated set-up, so called "name-based (virtual) hosting", the server chooses the content depending on the hostname.

This is how shared webhosts work: There's a single server, but depending on the requested hostname it spits out a different website for each name.

Therefore, if you want to tie your server content to your hostname, you have to tell your server to produce your website only for your desired name, and to produce a different (error) website for all other cases.

In Apache this is trivial to configure, just check their documentation; for IIS I wouldn't know but I imagine it's equally simple.

Comment: could you explain this a bit more? I'm a little lost on how to execute what you're asking in iis.

Comment: @Kerrek, what about specifying host header in IIS? (Keeping it simple)

Comment: @Waqas: I don't know IIS. Check the documentationo for "name-based hosting" or "name-based virtual hosting", something like that. Maybe someone else here can tell you how, check out @Bob Vale's answer for instance.

Comment: This is fairly trivial in IIS 7 on Windows 2008, using Host Headers

Answer (score 3):

If your hosting environment is IIS and you have admin access to it.  Set your default website to show an error page and then create a new site with the host header matching your domain to point to your website.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. It really works fast and solved my problem.

Insert this code in your .htacces

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.higueyrd.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.higueyrd.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Just put your domain.

Comment: it says it's an IIS server

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix you can do this . May be on home page load or BeginRequest .

```
if(!Request.Url.Host.ToLower().contains("mysite.com")){
  Response.Redirect("error.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In IIS there is a setting called [bindings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28WS.10%29.aspx) that allows you to select which hostnames your website will respond to.  This feature allows an instance of IIS to host mulitple websites on a single IP address.

If you want your site to only work for http://example.com/ and http://www.example.com/, you should set the bindings to only work for "example.com" and "www.example.com".

The exception here is if you are using SSL.  If you are, IIS cannot determine the hostname and you will most likely have to use a dedicated IP address for your site.  In that scenario, user608576's solution will work.  Although, I would put that code in your `Global.asax` file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    if( (request.Url.Host != "example.com") && (request.Url.Host != "www.example.com") )
    {
        response.Clear();
        response.Write("Unauthorized domain name: " + request.Url.Host);
        response.End();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right when i last check my sites cpanel i saw a feature that stopped redirections to my domain if checked. I´m using Hostso as my host so check their test cpanel for it.

Hope it helps alittle atleast :)

Fredrik wirth

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle in code then do it in Global.asax in BeginRequest as below

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!context.Request.Url.Host.ToLower().Equals("www.mydomain.com"))
    {
        context.Rewritepath("/invalidpage.aspx");
    }
}
```

The other simple way is to specify a host headers in IIS for your website.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx
Note: I am writing through my mobile so consider spelling mistakes

Comment: It is possible that host name does not contain "www"

Comment: yeah you are right, i was just suggesting my code may not exactly implemented.